# Apriori algorithm not showing result

Tags: python

I am using Python for market basket analysis. When I am executing this code, it only showing the column name without any result.

```
frequent_tr = apriori(data_tr, min_support=0.05)
```

[image]

Here is the dataset Removed

I have adjusted the min_support value but still showing the same result.

The library that I have used is

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import apriori
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import association_rules 
from mlxtend.preprocessing import TransactionEncoder
```

Then the following code is executed.

```
data = pd.read_csv(_link of the csv location_)

data_tr = data.groupby(['transaction_id', 'service_type']).sum().unstack().reset_index().fillna(0).set_index('transaction_id').droplevel(0,1)

TE = TransactionEncoder()
array = TE.fit(data_tr).transform(data_tr)
data_tr_encoded = pd.DataFrame(array, columns = TE.columns_)
frequent_tr_encoded = apriori(data_tr, min_support=0.05)
```

The final code result column name only.

I am expecting the final code will print the result like this:
[image: expected result]

**EDIT**

I have updated my code to display each of the service_type into column (refer to data_tr code above)

The output does not show each service_type
[image: Edited output]

Comment: Unless `apriori` is a new built-in function in `python`, you would need to post it here if you want other people to see what it does.

Comment: @Aryerez. I have included the library that I have used before execute any code. So, the apriori algorithm is not self built, it is part of the Python library.

Comment: https://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/frequent_patterns/apriori/#overview  the `apriori` function takes a dataframe as a param, not a csv file

Comment: Yup @Craicerjack  I read the data using data = pd.read_csv , after importing the mentioned library in my post. Thus, the data is in dataframe format

Comment: You should include all relevant code in your question

Comment: Please see http://sscce.org/ when asking others for programming help on the internet.

Comment: @Craicerjack, ok, updated all the library and code that I have executed until I get the error message.

Comment: what result are you expecting? I think you will need to adjust your `data_tr` variable as your coulmn names are just letters of the alphabet and not the items you are referring to

Comment: @Craicerjack, updated a screenshot of my expected result.

Comment: @Craicerjack I have make the service_type into column but the output after apply TransactionaEncoder is not quite right. Refer to the Edit part.

Comment: @RinshanKolayil   Can you post back the earlier message regarding making data_tr_list ?

Comment: @Azul `data_tr_list = data_tr.values.tolist()` , But it will not give you the expected output

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import apriori
from mlxtend.preprocessing import TransactionEncoder
data = pd.read_csv('Dataset - Transaction.csv')
data_tr = data.groupby(['geohash_user', 'service_type']).sum().unstack().reset_index().fillna(0).set_index('geohash_user').droplevel(0,1)
data_tr_list = pd.DataFrame(np.where(np.array(data_tr.values.tolist()) >= 1, 1,0),columns=data_tr.columns)
frequent_tr_encoded = apriori(data_tr_list, min_support=0.05,use_colnames=True)
```

Output (Same output of Mr.CarlosSR)

```
support itemsets
0   0.054093    (Aircond Repair)
1   0.186669    (Aircond Servicing)
2   0.090622    (Electrical Wiring / Power Point)
3   0.078008    (Local Moving - Budget Lorry)
4   0.060556    (Painting)
5   0.170405    (Plumbing Repair)
6   0.054093    (Aircond Repair)
7   0.186669    (Aircond Servicing)
8   0.090622    (Electrical Wiring / Power Point)
9   0.078008    (Local Moving - Budget Lorry)
10  0.060556    (Painting)
11  0.170405    (Plumbing Repair)
12  0.054093    (Aircond Repair)
13  0.186669    (Aircond Servicing)
14  0.090622    (Electrical Wiring / Power Point)
15  0.078008    (Local Moving - Budget Lorry)
16  0.060556    (Painting)
17  0.170405    (Plumbing Repair)
```

Second

```
data_tr = data.groupby(['transaction_id', 'service_type']).sum().unstack().reset_index().fillna(0).set_index('transaction_id').droplevel(0,1)
data_tr_list = pd.DataFrame(np.where(np.array(data_tr.values.tolist()) >= 1, 1,0),columns=data_tr.columns)
frequent_tr_encoded = apriori(data_tr_list, min_support=0.05,use_colnames=True)
```

Output

```
    support     itemsets
0   0.131081    (Aircond Servicing)
1   0.058486    (Electrical Wiring / Power Point)
2   0.050062    (Local Moving - Budget Lorry)
3   0.114593    (Plumbing Repair)
```

**EDIT**

The allowed values for a DataFrame by apriori function are True, False, 0, 1

Filtering SUM more than 2 along axis 1

```
data_tr_list = data_tr_list[data_tr_list.sum(axis=1) >= 2]
```

Comment: both of them does not apply TransactionEncoder. Without it, seems like no problem on result.

Comment: Because the each row of the data have same shape,Please refer https://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/preprocessing/TransactionEncoder/#example-1

Comment: thanks friend. 
TransactionEncoder will give boolean value and unique label name. Thus, I have printed out the shape of the 3 tables. 

In the end, I still need to go back to the unstack dataframe when applying the algorithm. 

Is this what you have discovered at this moment?

Even I have used the encoder with Boolean as value but I still need to filter transaction_id with more than 1 items. So, I will need to convert to numerical value. Does this mean the encoder is useless in my final result?

Comment: I don't think it is neccessary to go back to unstack the dataframe. Mr CarloSr already done the filtering more than two items. Encoder is not useless, you can convert boolean value to integer value where True becomes 1 and False becomes 0

Comment: Please refer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58435648/applying-transaction-encoder-on-dataset, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/apriori-algorithm/ and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementing-apriori-algorithm-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

Your csv has 142.155 rows and 142.103 unique transaction_id. That means that that only 52 of your transaction_id have more than one service_type... how do you intend to apply an apriori model with only 52 associations? Could it be that you are intending to do an apriori not based in the transaction level but on the geohash_user level?

Beside of that, and assuming you want to go with the user level analysis, quite not sure why you need to use TransformationEncoder.

I guess that what you are trying to achieve is your dataframe to have a 1 (True) if the value is higher than 0 and 0 (False) otherwise. At least, for using apriori that is what you are expected to use as input, because it doesn't mind whether in the same transaction there were 1 or 5 units of the same type.

```
def encode_units(x):
    if x<=0:
        return 0
    elif x >= 1:
        return 1


data = pd.read_csv('Dataset - Transaction.csv')

data_tr = data.groupby(['geohash_user', 'service_type']).sum().unstack().reset_index().fillna(0).set_index('geohash_user').droplevel(0,1)

data_tr_encoded2 = data_tr.applymap(encode_units)

data_tr_encoded_filt = data_tr_encoded2[(data_tr_encoded2 > 0).sum(axis=1) >= 2] #we only need users that have more than 1 service in order to get association rules

frequent_tr_encoded = apriori(data_tr_encoded_filt, min_support=0.05, use_colnames = True)
```

```
    support itemsets
0   0.054093    (Aircond Repair)
1   0.186669    (Aircond Servicing)
2   0.090622    (Electrical Wiring / Power Point)
3   0.078008    (Local Moving - Budget Lorry)
4   0.060556    (Painting)
5   0.170405    (Plumbing Repair)
6   0.054093    (Aircond Repair)
7   0.186669    (Aircond Servicing)
8   0.090622    (Electrical Wiring / Power Point)
9   0.078008    (Local Moving - Budget Lorry)
10  0.060556    (Painting)
11  0.170405    (Plumbing Repair)
12  0.054093    (Aircond Repair)
13  0.186669    (Aircond Servicing)
14  0.090622    (Electrical Wiring / Power Point)
15  0.078008    (Local Moving - Budget Lorry)
16  0.060556    (Painting)
17  0.170405    (Plumbing Repair)
```

Comment: I intend to use transaction_id when applying apriori just to let the model to get some knowledge about what item can buy together. Based on my opinion, we should do transaction_id and also geohash_user to get association rule then check whether the rule are logic or not. This is my opinion, do correct me if I am wrong. 

Regarding the number of unique data to apply apriori, even though the uniqueness is small, we should be able to find out the association rule as long as the data applied has purchase more than 1 item at the same time. Correct me again if I am wrong.

Comment: I have read though Medium and also Towards Data Science posts, some of them will use TransactionEncoder as their preprocessing, while some does not. 

May I know when do we need to apply TransactionEncoder? There is no explanation in online.